# Jcombobox with Jcheckboxes

Tags: java, rendering, jcombobox, jcheckbox

how can I create (with JAVA) Combobox that contains Checkboxes for multiple selection and display the selected items in the Combobox like this picture:
[click to see the pic](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/644480Sanstitre.png)

and thnx for advance.

**EDIT**:
I found this API ([JAPURA API](http://www.japura.org/checkcombobox)) and it's great but when I select multiple things I want to display the selected items instead of "* multiple items *".

Comment: See the following link [JComboBox Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link to achieve your goal:
[JComboBox Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Comment: thnx but this is not what I want. I want to display the items of combobox as checkboxes and display the selected items on the combobox

Comment: @SlimEN do you mean combobox with checkboxs items, and when you check an item from the combobox it will be displayed on another list ? (i mean two components the first is combobox with checkbox items and another list which contains the selected items from the combobox ?)

Comment: I want to make it like this photo: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/644480Sanstitre.png

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a JButton and style it in the form of a Combobox if you want that.

Then, at the onclick function (actionperformed), you create a JPanel and make it visible under the button. In the panel, you can put whatever you want, so you just put checkboxes there.

I know this is kind of a workaround of your problem, but it should be easy for you to do so, and the actual user does not see a difference at all.

Hope I could help you.

Cheers,

Lucky

Comment: is that mean that there is no way to create a combobox with checkboxes ?

Comment: no, it's not meant you cannt do this, this was just a suggestion to workaround your problem. i hope you can solve this and tell us how you did it.